# Тест на присутствие текста на странице selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, pytest

PAGE_TS001.py:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver

class DemoQA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        with open("conf.json") as data_file:
            parser = json.load(data_file)
        url = parser.get("URL")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get(url)

        #находим нужные поля
        fName = self.driver.find_element_by_id("name_3_firstname")
        lName = self.driver.find_element_by_id("name_3_lastname")
        phone = self.driver.find_element_by_id("phone_9")
        hobby = self.driver.find_element_by_name("checkbox_5[]")
        uName = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        email = self.driver.find_element_by_id("email_1")
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id("password_2")
        confirm = self.driver.find_element_by_id("confirm_password_password_2")
        submit = self.driver.find_element_by_name("pie_submit")

        #заполняем
        fName.send_keys(parser.get("First Name"))
        lName.send_keys(parser.get("Last Name"))
        hobby.click()
        phone.send_keys(parser.get("Phone Number"))
        uName.send_keys(parser.get("Username"))
        email.send_keys(parser.get("E-mail"))
        password.send_keys(parser.get("Password"))
        confirm.send_keys(parser.get("Confirm Password"))
        # кликаем сабмит
        submit.click()
        # hz nado/net zhdat`
        # driver.implicitly_wait(5)

ts = DemoQA()
```

TEST_TS001.py

```
import pytest
import page_TS001

def test_function():
    text = "Username already exists"
    assert (text in page_TS001.ts.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("piereg_login_error") == True)

test_function()
```

Ковыряю тестирование, есть два файла в проекте page и test соответсвенно, я не уверен, что верно написал тест, ровно как и не уверен, что нормально создал архитектуру проекта (моим знания по тестированию около 5 часов).

При этом имею при запуске Test_TS001.py:
https://pastebin.com/6exM1E4T

```
test_case_TS001.py:6: in test_function
    assert (text in page_TS001.ts.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("piereg_login_error") == True)
E   assert 'Username already exists' in [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="c5d20ee4-8285-49fb-a777-42862e1c3afa", element="90b84448-6b35-4133-8925-e0b8bb2c0503")>]
E    +  where [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="c5d20ee4-8285-49fb-a777-42862e1c3afa", element="90b84448-6b35-4133-8925-e0b8bb2c0503")>] = <bound method WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="c5d20ee4-8285-49fb-a777-42862e1c3afa")>>('piereg_login_error')
E    +    where <bound method WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="c5d20ee4-8285-49fb-a777-42862e1c3afa")>> = <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="c5d20ee4-8285-49fb-a777-42862e1c3afa")>.find_elements_by_class_name
E    +      where <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="c5d20ee4-8285-49fb-a777-42862e1c3afa")> = <page_TS001.DemoQA object at 0x036D4930>.driver
E    +        where <page_TS001.DemoQA object at 0x036D4930> = page_TS001.ts
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================== 1 error in 13.07 seconds ===========================
```

Тестовые данные в файле conf.json:

```
{
"URL":"http://demoqa.com/registration/",
"First Name": "David",
"Last Name": "Jones",
"Hobby": "0",
"Phone Number": "89377005211",
"Username": "DavidJonesZZ",
"E-mail": "johndoe@host.net",
"Password": "mysecret",
"Confirm Password": "mysecret"
}
```

Вопрос: почему не работает этот тест? (я проверяю на наличие текста text в поле с классом "piereg_login_error"). Или нужно использовать re?

ps. Пробовал также driver.page_source вместо конкретного поля - та же ошибка.

pps. Если нетрудно укажите на неточности, допущенные в работе.

Comment: Вам бы не помешало привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), потому что код из вопроса ни у кого не заработает (ведь ни у кого нет вашего сайта и тесту нечего тестировать у других людей), что сильно снижает шансы на получение помощи, потому что без воспроизводимого примера ответ на вопрос зачастую превращается в гадание на кофейной гуще, а это любят не все.

Comment: @andreymal, да, верно, это моё упущение:
исправил вопрос, добавил исходные данные
Это конструктивная критика! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements_by_class_name` возвращает список элементов. Если вы знаете, что у вас точно один такой элемент на странице, то используйте `find_element_by_class_name`. А чтобы получить текст внутри элемента, нужно использовать атрибут `text`. Чтобы заработало, вашу проверку нужно записать так:

```
assert text in page_TS001.ts.driver.find_element_by_class_name("piereg_login_error").text
```

Но это лишь локальное решение проблемы... Ваше опасение

> что нормально создал архитектуру проекта

вполне обоснованно. Что бы я поменял:

1. Убрать инциализацию объекта класса из `PAGE_TS001.py`
2. В `__init__()` оставить только инициализацию драйвера
3. Парсинг конфига вообще сделать в отдельном файле (чтобы отделить логику и данные). Обычно называют `data_providers.py`.
4. Шаги по регистрации нужно в самом тесте делать, но без поиска контролов. В идеале еще можно логику отдельно вынести, но это можно на более поздних этапах обучения написанию автотестов

В общем, тест должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
import page_TS001
import data_providers

def test_function():
    application = page_TS001.DemoQA()
    reg_page = application.open_registration_page()
    reg_page.enter_f_name(data_providers.first_name)
    reg_page.enter_l_name(data_providers.last_name)
    # ... ввод остального ...
    reg_page.click_submit()
    assert data_providers.text == reg_page.get_notification()
```

Еще рекомендую изучить явные ожидания и вставить их в нужных местах в методах класса `DemoQA`

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам, ибо разобрался:

```
assert (text in page_TS001.ts.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("piereg_login_error") == True)
```

надо изменить на

```
assert (text in page_TS001.ts.driver.page_source )
```

Comment: Проверять наличие текста сразу во всём исходном коде страницы — так себе идея, потому что текст может оказаться не в `piereg_login_error`, а в каком-нибудь другом месте, в результате чего тест проверит не то, что должен проверить. Рекомендую не сыпать оскорблениями по поводу того, что за какие-то несчастные два часа не нашлось спецов по Selenium, которые могли бы ответить на ваш вопрос (у людей работы и семьи, знаете ли, они не круглосуточно на ruSO сидят), а подождать денёк-другой, может спецы ещё подтянутся.

Comment: Я всё понимаю, но словить -4 на ровном месте с неплохо описанным вопросом (я отвечал и на более сумбурные). Цель сообщества делиться знаниями (Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers). Не умеешь терпимо помогать - уходи. 

То есть я мог задать пару тройку таких вопросов и словить автобан?

Про "Проверять наличие текста сразу во всём исходном коде страницы — так себе идея " - соглашусь, нашел page_source.

Comment: Я видел -4 у данного ответа, и минусы скорее всего были за оскорбления, пока модератор их не стёр. -4 у вопроса я не видел, но если они действительно были, то я соглашусь, что это плохо и неправильно. Тем временем спец, похоже, таки подтянулся в соседнем ответе :)